# Error installing vmc, vmc requires multi_json (~> 1.4.0, runtime)

Tags: ruby, vmc

I am trying to install cloud foundry tool:vmc on my mac(10.8.2).
In the terminal, I inputed this command, but get back the error:

> ERROR:  Error installing vmc:
>       vmc requires multi_json (~> 1.4.0, runtime)*

Then I check the version of Multi_json in my mac, it seems already been installed with 1.5.0:

```
$ gem list multi_json
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
multi_json (1.5.0)*
```

I don't know why it will get the error in vmc install, anyone meet the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~> 1.4.0` means >= 1.4.0 and < 1.5.0

Since there is not > 1.4.0 just install the 1.4.0 version with

`sudo gem install multi_json --version 1.4.0`

Notice that this can crash some other gems. Installing gems system wide is bad, but I guess you are not developing in ruby right? So you should be ok with this

Comment: Thanks. I find install multi_json 1.4.0 is not enough, it will still get some error error in later vmc useage. Finally, I also uninstall the original 1.5.0.